# Wifi and Cellular conflics

Tags: android

I am using Android 5.x to build an application. I have a problem with wifi and cellular mode. My wifi works well, first I call API via wifi, it's ok. Next, I disconnect the wifi and call API via cellular mode, it still works well. I am back to use wifi to call API, I get a problem here. Response throws Timeout exception. But I refresh the wifi then it's working ( reconnect ).
Note: I connect the device with a device outside, this provided cellular mode ( Icon of cellular mode on my device is nothing)

Comment: Which libs are you using for parsing Web Services in Android @Foxes

Comment: Hi @Venky I am using Retrofit2 and okhttp3

Comment: Did you tried add .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) this in program. But better I would suggest use Broadcast Receiver if you are jumping across networks

Comment: Thank for the response to me. But Retrofit already set default the timeout to 10s, I think that is not the way. I suggest the problem with network transport

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem following the below link. So I get a solution is set connectionPool of OkhttpClient.

```
builder.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
```

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html

> Create a new connection pool with tuning parameters appropriate for a single-user application. The tuning parameters in this pool are subject to change in future OkHttp releases. Currently this pool holds up to 5 idle connections which will be evicted after 5 minutes of inactivity.

[the same problem](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146)